# Dell PowerEdge T410 - How do I build additional 3 drive Raid 5 and keep SBS 2011 running?

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid5, windows-sbs-2011

**Dell PowerEdge T410 / Dell PERC 6/i**

3 x 1TB SATA in Raid 5 array split as 2 drives

(Drive 0  C: 128GB    E:1847GB)

(Drive 1  D: 20GB)

Currently running **SBS 2011 Standard**.

---

I would just appreciate some quick advice on the following. I am not familiar with this system configuration.

I have a very short time window (approx 1hr) where I can gain hands on access to this machine. I have remote access availability.

I need to add 3 additional 1TB drives and set them up as a Raid 5 array with only an hour of downtime for the Server.

I can add the physical drives, no problem.

**However I need to know if I can set the system to build the Raid 5 array whilst SBS is running.** I understand that the Raid 5 build could take up to 48 hours.

Is this possible?
Could someone with more experience talk me through this please.

Comment: Do you have Dell OpenManage Server Administrator installed on the server? I'm thinking you should be able to create a new RAID array and virtual disk in DOMSA without any downtime.

Comment: Hello Joaqwerity, To be honest I don't know. I will now try and check remotly.

Thank you